# How to make your minecraft not spawn hostile mobs but spawning friendly mobs and still get hungry?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I wanna play minecraft without any hostile mobs but only friendly mobs spawn. but, you still get hungry. if i type /gamerule doMobSpawning false, then the friendly mobs will despawn too right? I need Answers for this if it is possible

Answer (score 4):

With that gamerule they would not despawn, but no new ones would spawn. You could set up a command block to kill all hostile mobs as soon as they spawn, but that would drop their loot. You could also kill that loot, but that would make every string or water bottle that you drop in the ground vanish. So I suggest teleporting the mobs down into the void instead.

Put a repeating command block chain near to where you first spawned in the world (can be down in the bedrock) and put these commands in them:

```
/tp @e[type=elder_guardian] ~ -65 ~
/tp @e[type=wither_skeleton] ~ -65 ~
/tp @e[type=stray] ~ -65 ~
/tp @e[type=husk] ~ -65 ~
/tp @e[type=zombie_villager] ~ -65 ~
/tp @e[type=evocation_illager] ~ -65 ~
/tp @e[type=vindication_illager] ~ -65 ~
/tp @e[type=creeper] ~ -65 ~
/tp @e[type=skeleton] ~ -65 ~
/tp @e[type=spider] ~ -65 ~
/tp @e[type=zombie] ~ -65 ~
/tp @e[type=slime] ~ -65 ~
/tp @e[type=ghast] ~ -65 ~
/tp @e[type=zombie_pigman] ~ -65 ~
/tp @e[type=enderman] ~ -65 ~
/tp @e[type=cave_spider] ~ -65 ~
/tp @e[type=silverfish] ~ -65 ~
/tp @e[type=blaze] ~ -65 ~
/tp @e[type=magma_cube] ~ -65 ~
/tp @e[type=ender_dragon] ~ -65 ~
/tp @e[type=wither] ~ -65 ~
/tp @e[type=witch] ~ -65 ~
/tp @e[type=endermite] ~ -65 ~
/tp @e[type=guardian] ~ -65 ~
/tp @e[type=shulker] ~ -65 ~
/tp @e[type=drowned] ~ -65 ~
/tp @e[type=phantom] ~ -65 ~
/tp @e[type=pillager] ~ -65 ~
/tp @e[type=ravager] ~ -65 ~
```

If you prefer just one command for this, use this one:

```
/tp @e[type=!item,type=!xp_orb,type=!area_effect_cloud,type=!leash_knot,type=!painting,type=!item_frame,type=!armor_stand,type=!ender_crystal,type=!egg,type=!arrow,type=!snowball,type=!small_fireball,type=!ender_pearl,type=!eye_of_ender_signal,type=!potion,type=!xp_bottle,type=!fireworks_rocket,type=!spectral_arrow,type=!llama_spit,type=!tnt,type=!falling_block,type=!boat,type=!minecart,type=!chest_minecart,type=!furnace_minecart,type=!tnt_minecart,type=!hopper_minecart,type=!skeleton_horse,type=!donkey,type=!mule,type=!bat,type=!pig,type=!sheep,type=!cow,type=!chicken,type=!squid,type=!wolf,type=!mooshroom,type=!snowman,type=!ocelot,type=!villager_golem,type=!horse,type=!rabbit,type=!polar_bear,type=!llama,type=!parrot,type=!villager,type=!player,type=!lightning_bolt,type=!dolphin,type=!cod,type=!salmon,type=!tropical_fish,type=!pufferfish,type=!turtle,type=!cat,type=!fox,type=!panda,type=!trader_llama,type=!wandering_trader] 0 -65 0
```

But careful: This command is made in 1.14.0, any entity that gets added after that needs adjustments to the command or else it gets killed.

Comment: Teleporting flying monsters below bedrock should do just fine if you're playing in Survival with the exception of the ender dragon which can be killed with `/kill`.

Comment: One could also use `/tp @e[type=!Player,type=!Pig,type=!Cow,...] ~ 0 ~` for more efficient results. You would also have to exclude entities like Items, XP orbs, and Arrows in this scenario.

Comment: Hm, one problem I haven't thought of: The dragon would instantly create a portal. But I think if you want an easier game, it would be ok to just have the portal back home from the End instantly unlocked. @GalenNare Correct. I'll edit my answer to also include this second option.

Comment: Oh wow, my solution doesn't even work. All entities are constantly teleported to 0 0 0, so they are never in the void. I'll fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to do this using the [Bad Mobs](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/bad-mobs) mod.

## Installation

1. Make sure you've ran* the desired version of MC at least once. I've done this with 1.12.2.
2. Download [Minecraft Forge](https://files.minecraftforge.net/) for your version of Minecraft.
3. Run* Minecraft with the forge profile at least once.
4. [Download](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/bad-mobs/download) *Bad Mobs* and put it inside the *mods* folder in your Minecraft directory.**
5. Run* Minecraft with the forge profile at least once.
6. Edit the file `badmobs.cfg` inside the *config* folder in your Minecraft directory** using a text editor and add the mobs you want to ban.
   My list looks like this:

```
    S:bannedMobs <
        minecraft:blaze
        minecraft:creeper
        minecraft:drowned
        minecraft:elder_guardian
        minecraft:endermite
        minecraft:evoker
        minecraft:evoker_fangs
        minecraft:ghast
        minecraft:guardian
        minecraft:husk
        minecraft:magma_cube
        minecraft:phantom
        minecraft:shulker
        minecraft:silverfish
        minecraft:skeleton
        minecraft:slime
        minecraft:wither_skeleton
        minecraft:stray
        minecraft:spider
        minecraft:vex
        minecraft:vindicator
        minecraft:witch
        minecraft:zombie
        minecraft:zombie_villager
        minecraft:cave_spider
     >
```

You might want to include some other mobs, such as endermen and polar bears. The ID's to add to the block list are the [Entity ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGB9k.png) you can find at the mob's [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mob#List_of_mobs) page, prefixed with `minecraft:`.

---

* If you've reached the main menu, you're good.

** Your Minecraft directory is usually `~/.minecraft` on Mac/Linux or `%APPDATA%\.minecraft` on Windows